# "Symbol 'xxx' could not be resolved" because CDT indexer does not choose correct header file

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Situation: I have a big project where I have to implement certain "code units" that all rely on header files with the same name but sometimes different versions of the standard, this header file represents. So header files like "fmiFunctions.h" and "fmiFunctionTypes.h" exist multiple times in my project tree.

Problem: Compilation works fine, since the make file links the correct header file to each source file. But the CDT indexer does not know, which header file it has to take for type definitions, so I get the error "Symbol 'xxx' could not be resolved". When I hit F3, I can choose between the different header files.

Is there any way to tell the indexer, which header file to take for a specific source file or source folder?

Comment: a #include "<path>/filename"  should do what you want

Comment: This does not work for several reasons:
1. The locations of header files are given by the makefile structure in this project
2. Even if I make the compromise and use relative paths, the indexer doesn't seem to take #include "./fmiFunctions.h"